# How to read a .txt file of fixed length and identify each field by position

Tags: input, field, offset

I have a text file that is fixed length, with 8 fields making up each line. It is not a delimited file, but each field is a fixed length. For example:

field aaa starts in column 1 for 10 bytes, field bbb starts in column 11 for 6 bytes, field ccc starts in column 17 for 20 bytes, etc...

How can I read a line and identify each column?  I need to split the input to multiple output files, but the new output will be comprised of a new order of the individual fields.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that....I guess that WOULD help things a little....I am just using DOS batch file commands.